# Gain access to source code with functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to gain access to the source code on this site http://aptus-usa.com/calc which would enable me to simply have the functional calculator without the other links or the image. I've gained access to the source code (which I will post down below) and I also can successfully remove the links and the image. However, the functionality of the calculator is missing. What could cause this problem considering that according to the web links for the JavaScript files:

> http://aptus-usa.com/resources/jsmodernizr-2.6.1-respond-1.1.0.min.js
>
> http://aptus-usa.com/resources/jsjquery-1.8.2.min
>
> http://aptus-usa.com/resources/jsbootstrap.min.js

there are no files on the server?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Aptus USA | Plant Nutrition | Nutrient Feed Calculators</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/nc.css"/>
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>-->
<script src="http://aptus-usa.com/resources/jsmodernizr-2.6.1-respond-1.1.0.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://aptus-usa.com/resources/jsjquery-1.8.2.min" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://aptus-usa.com/resources/jsbootstrap.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>

<!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/base.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/ncstyles.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/ncPrint.css"/>
<script src="../assets/js/jquery.print.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/nc.js" type="application/javascript"></script>-->
</head>

<body>

<div id="logo"><img src="resources/img/APTUS Logo_planttech_Full.png" width="150" />
    <h2 style="color:white;font-size:1.3em;margin-top:40px;">Outdoor Growing or<br>Recirculating Hydroponics</h2>
    <p><a href="http://aptus-usa.com/resources/docs/AptusFeedSchedules.pdf" target="_blank" style="font-size:1.3em"><strong>Download Alternate<br>Feeding Schedules</strong></a></p>
</div>
<div id="downloads">

</div>

<form name="calc" method="post" target="_self">


<!--Variables table-->
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="variablesTable" id="id_variables">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center" class="cellHeader">NUTRIENT CALCULATOR</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="vegWeeks" id="id_vegWeeks">
                                                        <option value="1" selected>1</option>
                                                        <option value="2" >2</option>
                                                        <option value="3" >3</option>
                                                        <option value="4" >4</option>
                                                        <option value="5" >5</option>
                                                        <option value="6" >6</option>
                                                        <option value="7" >7</option>
                                                        <option value="8" >8</option>
                            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for="vegWeeks">Vegetative Weeks</label><br />
            <span class="subtitle">From clone/seed transplant to flowering</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="bloomWeeks" id="id_bloomWeeks">
                                                        <option value="1" >1</option>
                                                        <option value="2" >2</option>
                                                        <option value="3" >3</option>
                                                        <option value="4" >4</option>
                                                        <option value="5" >5</option>
                                                        <option value="6" >6</option>
                                                        <option value="7" >7</option>
                                                        <option value="8" >8</option>
                                                        <option value="9" selected>9</option>
                                                        <option value="10" >10</option>
                                                        <option value="11" >11</option>
                                                        <option value="12" >12</option>
                            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for="bloomWeeks">Bloom Weeks</label><br />
            <span class="subtitle">Including the final 'flush' week</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="resSize" id="id_resSize" value="5" size="6">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for="resSize">Gallons in Reservoir</label><br />
            <span class="subtitle">
                For full cycle nutrient needs, enter your total weekly water usage.<br />
                Or, enter your reservoir size for specific mixing instructions.
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The calculator posts back to the server to get its results, so you won't be able to run it just on the client. You could use an iframe to achieve a similar result:

```html
<iframe src="http://aptus-usa.com/calc" width="800" height="500">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

One other thing to note, you should check if you have permission to use the calculator for your own purposes.

Comment: I need to remove the link and the image on the page.

Comment: You can't using the iframe as the page is on a different domain ([XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)). Have you asked the author of the original calculator if you can use it as you intend to?

Comment: Someone from the company had contacted me about it. It isn't for my own purposes. They want to embed the calculator onto their square space site but they don't have access to the source code. However, she mentioned they had access to the hosting site.

Answer (score 1):

From a cursory look at that page, it seems like the calculations happen on the server as a result of the the form POST, not the client. You won't be able to access that code without access to the server.

Comment: If can gain access to the server, what would I need to do next in order for the code to be functional on another site?

Comment: Unless you know the owner of the site and have login details to the server, you will not be able to access it.

Comment: I should be receiving the login information shortly. When I gain access to it, what would I need to do next in order for the code to be functional on another site?

Comment: This is getting off topic from what was originally asked.